# Why does iterating list(dict1.keys()) work and iterating dict1 directly not work here?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Here's the task that I was give:
[image]

This was the first attempt. And I understand that the size of `dict1` is changing so the loop cannot iterate it properly.

[image]

I tried the following code and it worked. But I don't understand why?
[image]

Yes I'm iterating a list in the second code but that list is directly dependent on `dict1`.
Either the list is not changing in size (please explain why) or the list is changing in size but somehow the code now works for a changing iteration (again please explain why).

It seems like the latter cause the following code works.
[image]

I don't understand how though? I'm changing the list size after every iteration. Then why does it not disturb the loop iteration here but it does disturb it in the first case when the dictionary was being iterated.

Comment: Because you're *not* changing the size of the list. Answer your own question: take a dictionary, create the list of its keys, add to the dictionary, look at what's now in the key list.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else already mentioned, in the code that works, you're iterating through a new list of the dictionary's keys, but you're not actually modifying that list in the iteration.

In the code that doesn't work, you're modifying the dictionary while iterating through a `dict.keys()` view object, which Python doesn't like.

Answer (score -2):

> **keys** Returns a copy of the dictionary’s list of keys.

[The docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/keys.html) say that `dict.keys` return a COPY of the keys, not as a direct reference. This means, after your first call of `dict.keys`, the list doesn't reflect your new changes on the dictionary object.

EDIT: Wrong answer, sorry guys. Doc found was not the official one.

EDIT 2 : list(dict.keys()) returns a list of the keys at the time of the call, so it's still the same idea : the iterated list does not reflect real changes.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys

Comment: That's not the actual Python docs. That's some rando's severely out of date, not very good attempt at writing their own docs for Python. Plus, the whole site is based on Python 2, which hit end of life years ago. jonrsharpe's link is the actual Python docs.